# How can I store a remote server variable to local server variable with ssh?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm making a bash script that exits if the remote server has a specific file and specific contents.
I check the file with the code below:

```
ssh $DEPLOY_HOST 'VAR=false

if [ -f /filename ]; then
    . /filename
    REMOTEID=$ID
        if [ "$REMOTEID" == "something" ]; then
                VAR=true
        fi
else
    echo "Missing /filename"
fi

if [ "$VAR" == false ]; then
    exit 1
fi
'
```

But that exit command doesn't work for local server, so the afterward code is executed, which I don't expect.
I think I have to get the result variable(VAR) from the remote server so that the local server can decide whether to exit or not with the variable.
How can I solve this?
Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
ssh $REMOTE 'test -e file' && exit
```

where `file` is the name of the file on the REMOTE server that you want to check for existence.

The exit code from the `test` command on the REMOTE server will be passed through `ssh`'s exit code into your local shell and be used with the `&&` operator.

---

If you need to return the string value of a variable, you could use this pattern:

```
VAR=$(ssh $REMOTE '
{
    some command
    some other command
    ...
    # all of the stdout from these commands will be discarded
} > /dev/null
echo $VAR # the stdout from here will be returned as stdout from ssh
')
```

Let's break this down:

- The `{}` block groups all commands where we want to discard stdout.
- The `''` single quotes capture all of the commands to run on the REMOTE server
- The `VAR=$(ssh ' ... ')` command will take stdout from the `echo $VAR` and place it in the local variable named `VAR`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but actually there's more than just checking the file existence. Sorry for giving insufficient information. I can only execute the afterward codes when the remote server has a certain file, and when the file has a certain variable.

Comment: Okay I'll add more to the answer.

Comment: Thanks for your elaboration!! This solved my problem :) Have a nice day!